# How to estimate a constant in the equation based on data

Tags: r, constants, estimation, data-fitting

I get a data series from the experiment {x1, x2, x3, x4, x5....Xn}.

xn is the reading of an instrument, which switch between column 1 and column 2. X2n+1 is the reading for column 1, whose volume is V1; while x2n is the reading for column 2, whose volume is V2.

I know that there are two equations can describe the relationship among them:

[image]

I need to estimate the constant A in the equation based on the measured data in the two situation:

1. known V1 and V2;
2. Unknown V1 and V2;

What's the method that I can use to estimate the A in the equations?

Comment: You could do it with the optim routine, but last time I suggested that I got downvoted, so I will wait and see what others suggest.

Comment: Am I missing something or are those equations not equivalent?  If you step forward in your data series by one then x2n-1 becomes x2n no? If so then V1==V2 or am I off in think about this?

Comment: A [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) would be helpful here to test possible solutions. Your model doesn't appear to account for any randomness; how do you want to find the "best" solution? Do you want a least squares fit? You should know how you want to model your data, if you do not, you'd bet better off asking at [stats.se] what methods would be most appropriate for your data.